# How to use crossfilter with sigma.js and canvas

Tags: crossfilter, sigma.js

I'm really not sure how to get started trying to use crossfilter to change my network visualisation (generated using sigma.js - which uses canvas to draw the visualisation). I'm relatively new to js.

Basically I want the size of my nodes to reflect values tied to dates which I want to filter using crossfilter.

Is this possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [linkurious.js](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/) (a fork of sigma) and it's filter plugin. Here's a demo: https://rawgit.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/develop/examples/filters.html